# Python indenting numpy matrix yields different results to printing matrix fully

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

It would seem that printing the ndarray object yields different results than indenting the ndarray itself.

In my code, I've taken a ndarray of 128x128 elements which contain mostly zeros but a few non-trivial numbers and printed them out in two different ways. The first I've used

```
print(array[:][32])
```

and second I've used

```
print(array[33][32])
```

to try and find the 33 element value.

When I do it using the former method, I get 0 at element 33,32. With the latter, I get 23. Is there a subtlety I'm missing in terms on how to use ndarrays?

Comment: With arrays, `[:]` does nothing, it's not even a placeholder.  `arr[:, 32]` is a valid way of indexing a 2d array.  `arr[:][32]` is the same as `arr[32]` which can also be written as `arr[32,:]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you mean by 33 element value. Here you deal with a 2D matrix.

Please note that for simplicity. I'll say xth row for the (x+1) row

In the second case you are taking the element in the `33rd row` and `32th column`, it's equivalent to `array[33,32]`

In the first case you are returning the 32th row.

What is important to note is that here you are doing chain indexing.

`array[:,32]` (which will return all the value of the 32th column) is not equivalent to `array[:][32]` that will first return your array then you'll take the 32th row.

Comment: So to double check array[:][32] will return array[:] then array[32]?

Comment: Yes you are right, when you do array[:] , it's like doing nothing. So basically it's like calling array[32] when you do array[:][32]

Answer (score 0):

Don't index 2D arrays "twice" like you're doing, that's not the right syntax for Numpy. Instead do:

```
print(array[:, 32])
```

or

```
print(array[33, 32])
```

depending on what value you're trying to actually extract. The top `print` statemnent gives you the `32`nd column of the array (which in your case should be a 1D array of shape `(128,)`), while the latter `print` statement should just give you the single value at row `33`, column `32`.

## Explanation

- `array[:][32]`

  - `array[:]` will just return the whole array. Thus, `array[:][32]` is equivalent to just calling `array[32]`. This will return the `32`nd row (counting from `0`) of `array`, which in your case should contain `128` values.
- `array[33][32]`

  - `array[33]` will return the `33`rd row of a 2D array. This will be a 1D array of shape `(128,)`. Next, the index `[32]` will be applied to that returned row, so you'll end up with the single value at row `33` column `32`. Thus in this case:

    ```
    array[33][32] == array[33, 32]
    ```
  - However, the repeated indexing syntax is still a Bad Idea. It's slower than using syntax like `array[33, 32]` (since `array[33][32]` will trigger two separate indexing operations). Also, it can result in unexpected behavior. For example, if you were to try to assign to the indexed value:

    ```
    array[33][32] = 19
    ```

    this might not end up changing any values in `array`, since there's a chance that by repeating the index operation `array[33][32]` will return a copy of the original array.

Comment: I think you forgot to finish your post.

Comment: Forgot nothing. I'm in the middle of revising it

Comment: Sorry having trouble conceptualising this. So what's the difference between calling array[:,32] and array[:][32]?

Comment: See the first part of my explanation section. You can simplify `array[:][32]` to just `array[32]`, which will return the `32`nd row. On the other hand, `array[:,32]` says something like "return the 32nd entry in every row", or, in other words, the `32`nd column.

Comment: @tel ah I see thank you very much